# Add automatic comments upon opening and closing a HTML tag in PhpStorm

Tags: html, syntax, phpstorm

I want to add HTML comments proceeding each `<div class="">` / `<div id="">` and their respective `</div>`'s.

For example, say I have a `<div class="main-container">`, I want a comment right after it to be `<!-- Start of .main-container -->`

And then after its `</div>` I want a `<!-- End of .main-container -->`

An example of what everything would look like:

```
<div id="container"> <!-- Start of #container -->
    <div class="container-text"> <!-- Start of .container-text -->
        <h2> Foo </h2>
    </div> <!-- End of .container-text -->
</div> <!-- End of #container -->
```

Is there any way to automate this with PhpStorm? I can't figure it out, any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and No at the same time.

**Option 1:** Create and use custom **[Live Template](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm)** where you can have any text/code you want. For example:

```
<div id="$NAME$"> <!-- Start of #$NAME$ -->
    $END$
</div> <!-- End of #$NAME$ -->
```

---

**Option 2:** If you are using **[Emmet](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Generating+Code+in+PhpStorm#GeneratingCodeinPhpStorm-Emmet%28ZenCoding%29)** .. it has an option (a filter in Emmet terms) to add closing comment.

That's where "no" part comes in: 1) only closing comment and 2) it will be placed on new line (depends on your code formatting settings, I guess) and have a bit different style:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Such option is available at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet | HTML --> Comment tags`

[image]

Comment: I was able to create a Live Template which works perfect except for the end comment, it renders on a new line instead of to the right of `</div>`, how can I fix this?

Comment: It must be code formatter. You can disable "reformat ..." option in that Live Template so no reformatting is done when Live Template gets expanded.

Comment: Great answer!I just have a question.I am using the first method and to make it work I must type div (the shortcut) and then press tab.I don't get thought how can I use the second method.Does it work automatically or should I press a button?Thank you!

Comment: @skiabox Well -- I'd say -- do not type `div` for #1 (any real tag) -- give it some another name (e.g. `qq`) that does not correspond to any real/standard tag. #2 works automatically -- it's Emmet in action. So typing `.container[TAB]` will do just that (check [emmet.io](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/) site for abbreviation docs)