# Anyway to do auto comments in PhpStorm at the end of code blocks?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

In **PhpStorm** is there any way (such as via a KB shortcut) for it to insert comments at the end of code blocks to note that's the end of said block?

For example, say you have this code:

```
<section class="category">
    <header>Some Header</header>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ille incendat? Quis istud, quaeso, nesciebat? Prioris generis est docilitas, memoria; Qui est in parvis malis. </p>

        <p>Paria sunt igitur. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Cui Tubuli nomen odio non est? Laboro autem non sine causa; </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

On the line directly after `</section>` is there anyway for it to input something like `<!-- Category Ends -->` simply by hitting a KB shortcut?

Comment: For existing code -- I'm not aware of such functionality/plugin. For brand new code see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37067602/783119

Comment: Thanks. I guess I would find it far more useful for existing code than new code as I never know beforehand if the block is going to get too long that it is going to require one.

Comment: Maybe just use custom Live Template then -- you will only have to type your block name (`Category` in your example) afterwards. I do not see any other ways (unless some plugin can do this). But in general -- I do not see the huge need for such comments as in IDE or browser you can see (and jump to) what the current block is ("breadcrumbs" functionality that shows your current tag path) -- at least for me it's good enough.

Comment: Well I guess there isn't a huge need for it as you say; just thought it would be a helpful shortcut to avoid having to type things out yourself each time, even if it's just the class/id name.