# Automatic Html Comment Tag

Tags: javascript, php

I had a project and it's done, instead of creating it manually, I want to automatically add an automatic html comment tag (<! - /.divname ->) for all html "div" classes. Which program should I use for this?

can you please help thanks.

Comment: Dont post images of code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add automatic comments upon opening and closing a HTML tag in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063034/add-automatic-comments-upon-opening-and-closing-a-html-tag-in-phpstorm)

Comment: I tried the 2nd option, activated the options, uploaded my design to php storm, then do I need to do something? because html comment tags are not added directly.